# Uber between countries (EU)?

Tags: europe, spain, portugal, uber

I'm traveling with my family from Faro (Portugal) to Seville (Spain.) It is about a two-hour drive and I found Uber to be one of the most pleasant and reasonably cost-effective ways to travel in Portugal.
Is it possible to cross into Spain with an Uber?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible if the driver doesn't mind?

Comment: @TomasBy So? What is the problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question is if a ride from Faro, PT to Seville, ES can be ordered in the Uber app, and if not, if this is just a technicality or if the company does not allow border crossings.

Comment: The bus is by far the easiest way to get to Sevilla from Faro and back.

Answer (score 4):

I've tested just now and the app returned the options. 191 euros is the cheapiest option.
So yes you should be able to request an Uber for this trip.

Comment: Id get the bus instead

Answer (score -2):

If you and the driver are citizens of Schengen countries, and/or eligible for the 90/180 rule (and not in violation of it), **and** the driver is willing, then the answer is yes.

If not, then you'd **probably** get away with it anyway, but I don't recommend it.  The consequences of getting caught can be significant.

Comment: The question is about Uber. I think we can assume they are all there legally.

Comment: I generally avoid assuming things that might not be true.  Myriads of people eligible for 90/180 no-visa visits have overstayed because it's so easy to get away with it.

Comment: There is so much wrong in this answer. You don't have to be a citizen of a Schengen country to be allowed to work in both Spain and Portugal and if the driver is a non-EEA citizen on a visa-free visit, he wouldn't be allowed to work neither in Spain nor in Portugal, even if he hasn't overstayed. In any case, the passengers will not be required to check the driver's work permit and immigration status and have no significant consequences to fear if they are stopped when driven by an illegal driver.

Comment: If (unlikely but possible) the driver is illegal and caught, the passenger has to find another way to get to his/her destination.  And if his/her visit to one country is by visa, that does not apply to the other country.